# Ошибка при выводе данных из базы данных

Tags: python, sqlite3

Код:

```py
import random
import sqlite3


def randomizer():
    cards = ['mbc20017', '25bmw320d', '26bmwx3']
    get_card = random.choice(cards)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM user_regular_card WHERE user_id={}'.format(get_card, '942912999'))
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

    for gtc in users:
        print(gtc[0])

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


randomizer()
```

Ошибка:

```py
    cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM user_regular_card WHERE user_id={}'.format(get_card, '942912999'))
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "26bmwx3"
```

Моя цель заключается, чтобы по выбору из рандома выбрать столбец и вывести из него данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имена некоторых ваших столбцов начинаются с цифры. Попробуйте для них использовать обратные апострофы, например так, что вместо

```
cards = ['mbc20017', '25bmw320d', '26bmwx3']
```

примените

```
cards = ['`mbc20017`', '`25bmw320d`', '`26bmwx3`']
```